# Conditional distribution function for two standard normal variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, solution-verification

Let $U,V$ have a bivariate normal distribution with joint density $f_{u,v}(u,v)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{u^2+v^2-2\rho uv}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right)$ where $\rho\in(-1,1)$ is the correlation coefficient. I want to show that the conditional distribution of $U$ given $V=v$ is distributed as $N(\rho v,1-\rho^2)$ for all $v\in\mathbb{R}$. We are allowed to assume $U,V$ are $N(0,1)$ variables.

My attempt: By definition of the conditional density function we have $f_{u|v}(u|v)=\frac{f_{u,v}(u,v)}{f_v(v)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp(-\frac{u^2+v^2-2\rho uv}{2(1-\rho^2)})}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{v^2}{2})}$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(\rho v)^2+u^2-2\rho uv}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right)$$

I know I basically need to show this is the density function of a $N(\rho v,1-\rho^2)$ variable, but I am having problems with this - if we read off the mean and variance we should have $2\sigma^2=2(1-\rho^2)$ and so $\sigma^2=1-\rho^2$, and the mean is $\rho v$. But in the very first part before the exponent, surely we should have $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}$? As the current form for my solution is incompatible with this. Any help would be really useful.

Comment: It seems that you lost the factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ :
$$\frac{\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp(-\frac{u^2+v^2-2\rho uv}{2(1-\rho^2)})}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{v^2}{2})}=\pmb{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\Big(-\frac{(\rho v)^2+u^2-2\rho uv}{2(1-\rho^2)}\Big)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's focus on  your original exponent:

$$-\frac{u^2+v^2-2\rho uv}{2(1-\rho^2)}$$

observe that we can manipulate it in the following manner

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
-\frac{u^2+v^2-2\rho uv\pm\rho^2v^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}=-\frac{v^2}{2}-\frac{(u-\rho v)^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}
\qquad (1) 
}
$$

substituing this new exponent in you original joint density you will prove what you are asked to do.

In fact you will find

$$f_{UV}(u,v)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-v^2/2}\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}e^{-(u-\rho v)^2/2(1-\rho^2)}=f_V(v)\cdot f_{U|V}(u|v)$$

where

$$V\sim N(0;1)$$

$$(U|V)\sim N(\rho v;1-\rho^2)$$

mean and variance of the conditional density are immediately shown in the second addend of the manipulated exponent in (1)

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean my solution was basically correct just with that small error?

Comment: @turkey131 : yes exactly. Anyway I suggest you to follow my solution which contains a common trick to solve problems like this.